# aes encrytion - content size not in multiples of 16bytes

Tags: java, ios, iphone, aes

i have a data which his close to 735 bytes, when i encrypt and send it to server server is able to encrypt until say 720 (in multiples of 16) but not anything beyond that, how to fix this problem, all i need is a kind of solution which will clear this problem.

```
NSMutableData *cipherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: content.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    CCCryptorStatus
    result = CCCrypt(((shouldEncrypt)?kCCEncrypt:kCCDecrypt), // operation
                     kCCAlgorithmAES128, // Algorithm - AES128 means the block size, not the keysize 
                     kCCOptionECBMode, // options
                     key.bytes, // key
                     kCCKeySizeAES256, // keylength
                     NULL,// iv
                     content.bytes, // dataIn
                     content.length, // dataInLength,
                     cipherData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                     cipherData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                     &outLength); // dataOutMoved
```

Comment: Can't you put some padding at the end to go to the next multiple of 16 ?

Comment: @FlorentBayle Doing your own padding is not hard and probably does not lead to vulnerabilities, but it is probably better to use the platform defined padding. Note to thndrkiss : ECB mode is not secure. Neither is sending ciphertext that has no HMAC authentication tag appended to it. Use TLS whereever possible instead. Just using AES does not make your protocol secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In options, (binary) OR the `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` flag to the `kCCOptionECBMode` flag.

This will automatically pad the last block to the block size. Note that this will also add a full block if a integral number of blocks is present (otherwise the data cannot be distinguished from the padding).